# Need help in verifying if I am taking the derivative of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\cos(x)}$ correctly

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to take the derivative of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\cos(x)}$.
What I am doing:

$$f'(x) = \frac{d\ (x\cos(x)^{-1})}{d \ x} + (\frac{d\ (x\cos(x)^{-1})}{d\ (\cos(x))} * \frac{d\ \cos(x)}{d\ x})$$

$$f'(x) = 1 + (- x(\cos(x)^{-2}) * (-\sin(x))) $$

... is it correct?

Comment: This is a simple "quotient rule"/"product rule" derivative...I have no idea what you are doing...

Comment: Not correct. At first glance, it seems to me that you’re trying to force your function into the chain-rule category.

Comment: I sort of get the $\cos(x)^{-1}$...but that is very confusing (and ultimately very unnecessary)...you should instead write, if you must (which I never would): $\big(\cos(x)\big)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise simply using the quotient rule formula
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}.$$
Setting $f(x)=x, g(x)=\cos x$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{\cos x}=\frac{1\cos x+x\sin x}{\cos^2 x}. $$
You can simplify this further if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative, using the quotient rule, should be very simply:

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\cos(x)}\right) =&\ \frac{1\cos(x) - x(-\sin(x))}{\cos^2(x)} \\
=&\ \frac{\cos(x) + x\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \\
=&\ \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)} + x\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \\
=&\ \frac{1}{\cos(x)} + x\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(x)} \\
=&\ \sec(x) + x\tan(x)\sec(x) \\
=&\ \sec(x)\big(1 + x\tan(x)\big)
\end{align}